# Nuget Install A Package

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure, nuget

I am trying to install "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64" using Nuget on Visual studio. I got the following error. What does it mean? Thanks

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64

Install-Package : Solution is not saved. Please save your solution before managing NuGet packages. At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x64
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetUnsavedSolution,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: did you try saving and building your project before running Install-Package?

Comment: I do not have a project yet. I am hoping to install project later on.

Comment: benPearce is right. After downloading the source code and save the project, I was able to do the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0. So install the NuGet package to solution without any project is not supported. You need create a project, then add the package to the project.